# Сортировка массива в Python

Tags: python

Допустим у нас есть массив из 500 эл как можно его отсортировать найти и вывести меньшие 5 эл???

Comment: numpy вам не поможет ?

Comment: Поставлю-ка я минус за "Покажите, что вы пробовали, что вы нашли (на этом сайте или в другом месте), и почему это не решает вашу проблему."

Comment: @Интик да тут и без нампи элементарно

Comment: `sorted(a)[:5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация по Python советует использовать [heapq.nsmallest(n)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) если нужно получить небольшое (относительно размера списка) количество наименьших элементов. Для больших значений `n` рекомендуют использовать [функцию `sorted()`, как показал @entithat в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1137272/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python#comment1966765_1137272), чтобы отсортировать весь список:

> The latter two functions perform best for smaller values of `n`. For
>   larger values, it is more efficient to use the `sorted()` function.
>   Also, when `n==1`, it is more efficient to use the built-in `min()` and
>   `max()` functions. If repeated usage of these functions is required,
>   consider turning the iterable into an actual heap.

Пример:

```
from heapq import nsmallest

res = nsmallest(5, items)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[ваши 500 элементов]
n=[]
for i in range(5):
    n.append(min(a))
    a.remove(min(a))
print(a)
```